# install_name_tool does nothing

Tags: macos, deployment, install-name-tool

I'm preparing my application for deployment on OSX.
The only problem is relocating the shared libraries.

I put them all inside a Frameworks-folder in the .app-folder itself.

What I try for every library is something like:

```
install_name_tool \
   -id @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtSql.framework/Versions/4/QtSql \
   MyProgram.app/Contents/MacOS/MyProgram


install_name_tool \
    -change QtSql @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtSql.framework/Versions/4/QtSql \
    MyProgram.app/Contents/MacOS/MyProgram
```

When I run otool -L on my executable again **nothing changed**.This is still the output:

```
kqoauth.framework/Versions/0/kqoauth (compatibility version 0.95.0, current version 0.95.0)
QtDeclarative.framework/Versions/4/QtDeclarative (compatibility version 4.7.0, current version 4.7.3)
QtScript.framework/Versions/4/QtScript (compatibility version 4.7.0, current version 4.7.3)
QtCore.framework/Versions/4/QtCore (compatibility version 4.7.0, current version 4.7.3)
QtSvg.framework/Versions/4/QtSvg (compatibility version 4.7.0, current version 4.7.3)
QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui (compatibility version 4.7.0, current version 4.7.3)
QtSql.framework/Versions/4/QtSql (compatibility version 4.7.0, current version 4.7.3)
QtXmlPatterns.framework/Versions/4/QtXmlPatterns (compatibility version 4.7.0, current version 4.7.3)
QtNetwork.framework/Versions/4/QtNetwork (compatibility version 4.7.0, current version 4.7.3)
/usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.9.0)
/usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 832.0.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 125.2.10)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try

```
install_name_tool \
    -change QtSql.framework/Versions/4/QtSql \
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtSql.framework/Versions/4/QtSql \
    MyProgram.app/Contents/MacOS/MyProgram
```

?  You likely need to use the full current install name as shown on `otool -L`.

Comment: that was correct, thank you.
It's still a lot of work to fix the dependencies of all libraries.