# Relative Paths In Executables

Tags: linux, macos, environment-variables, relative-path

On Mac/Linux, library calls to open files (fopen, etc..) with relative paths in executables are relative to the current directory of the terminal and if I double click from folder relative to the user home directory (I think). How do I make relative paths relative to the executable for both instances (running on terminal and double clicking from folder) without changing any code? I think it has something to do with environment variables but I'm not sure.

Comment: You need something to [chdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html) to the wanted directory, and that something is probably not an environment variable. Perhaps making a shell wrapping a `cd` and the real program might help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set dependency path relative to @executable_path or @loader_path using `install_name_tool`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282889/install-name-tool-does-nothing) for some additional info on how to use it.
Use `otool -L <your_executable>` to see all dependencies.
For the info about @executable_path and @loader_path see [`man dyld`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/dyld.1.html)